# Porting from Gson to Jackson, confusion around generics and custom deserializers

Tags: android, json, jackson, gson, json-deserialization

We are trying to evaluate Jackson as an alternative to Gson and I'm running into issues understanding generics. I feel like its a simple problem that I am completely missing the answer to and am not finding examples/info via google or the documentation. I hope someone can point out my errors or point me to the right implementation.

Say I have a class like this:

```
public class Response<T extends BaseTypeInterface > implements BaseTypeInterface {
    private Meta meta;
    private T mResult;
    private Group<Notification> notifications;
}
```

I want to make a custom serializer for it, but nothing I do will let me get the type `T` info in the deserializer.
In theory I want to do `SimpleModule.addDeserializer(Response.class, new ResponseV2Serializer<BaseTypeInterface>());`
And then in the deserializer, I want to read the type information passed from `ObjectMapper.readValue(string, TypeReference<Response<SomeClassExtBaseTypeInterface>)`.

With my current custom deserializer I implemented the `ContextualDeserializer` in hopes of extracting the type info from `BeanProperty` but every time its called the `BeanProperty` is null.

```
public static class ResponseSerializer<T extends BaseTypeType>
        extends JsonDeserializer<Response<T>>
        implements ContextualDeserializer {

    @Override
    public ResponseV2<T> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property) 
        throws JsonMappingException {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Sample Json would look like this:

```
{
    meta: {
        code: 200,
        requestId: "541fb2dc498e306d526f7e4c"
    },
    response: {
        //content
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

reading you problem and needs, I undestood that you whant to have several datarepresentations and change it. For exemple the response can old a list some times and values another time depending of the request. If this is what you want to do, I think that you can go straight to the solution doing so :

- Response 1: formatted as you wanted
- Response 2: is presenting a list of animals

We use heritage to solve your problem.
The advantage of this solution,is that you do not needto write your serialized/deserializer. Try to avoid doing that : it's buggy and error prone... and often can lead to slow / complex serialization. :)

```
package com.rizze.labs;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    /**
     * 
     * @author je@rizze.com
     *
     */

    public class SOFW26026792 {


        @Test
    public void fromJsonToJackson() throws IOException{

        TheBean bean = new TheBean();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        //toJson
        String beanJson=mapper.writeValueAsString(bean);
        System.out.println("Response1 "+beanJson);

        //fromJson
        TheBean beanCopy = mapper.readValue(beanJson, TheBean.class);
        assertTrue(bean.meta.requestId.equals(beanCopy.meta.requestId));
        System.out.println("Response1 is OK");
    }


    @Test
    public void response2() throws IOException{

        TheBean2 animals = new TheBean2();
        animals.fillDatas();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        //toJson
        String animalsJson=mapper.writeValueAsString(animals);
        System.out.println("Response2 (Animals Response) "+animalsJson);

        //fromJson
        TheBean2 animalsCopy = mapper.readValue(animalsJson, TheBean2.class);
        assertTrue(animals.meta.requestId.equals(animalsCopy.meta.requestId));
        System.out.println("Response2 (Animals Response) is OK");
    }



    public static class TheBean{
        public RRMeta meta ;        
        public Object response; 

        public TheBean(){
            meta = new RRMeta();
            response = new RResponse();
            meta.code=200;
            meta.requestId="id:12312342325252345234234";
        }

    }


    public static class RRMeta{
        public int code;
        public String requestId;
        public RRMeta(){

        }
    }

    public static class TheBean2 extends TheBean{

        public TheBean2(){
            meta = new RRMeta();
            response = new RResponseAnimals();
        }
        public void fillDatas(){

            meta.code=200;
            meta.requestId="id:animal:4";

            ((RResponseAnimals)response).fillDatas();
        }
    }

    public static class RResponse{

        public String val1;
        public String val2;

        public RResponse(){
            val1="example";
            val2="yummi";

        }
    }   



    public static class RResponseAnimals {

        public ArrayList<String> animals= new ArrayList<String>();

        public RResponseAnimals addAnimal(String animal ){
            if(animals == null)animals=new ArrayList<String>();
            animals.add(animal);
            return this;
        }

        public RResponseAnimals(){}

        public void fillDatas(){
            addAnimal("snow monkey")
            .addAnimal("royal ant")
            .addAnimal("pink panther")
            .addAnimal("Blue elephant");
        }
    }   



}
```

Here is the console output of execution of this junits :

```
Response1 {"meta":{"code":200,"requestId":"id:12312342325252345234234"},"response":{"val1":"example","val2":"yummi"}}
    Response1 is OK
    Response2 (Animals Response) {"meta":{"code":200,"requestId":"id:animal:4"},"response":{"animals":["snow monkey","royal ant","pink panther","Blue elephant"]}}
    Response2 (Animals Response) is OK
```

Gist complete code : 
https://gist.github.com/jeorfevre/c0b4674a6a6bcd82630f